# Adding a drive to a Dell Poweredge 2950

Tags: linux, dell, dell-perc

I'm trying to add a drive to a dell poweredge 2950 running RedHat, which already has two drives in RAID 1.  The third drive is intended to be separate and without RAID.  I've added a virtual drive using Perc, and initialized it.  Now /dev/sdc is present.

```
    fdisk  /dev/sdc
```

run as root gives "Unable to open /dev/sdc".  What steps do I need to get the drive formatted mounted and online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's sdc?  Try using "fdisk -l" to determine all of the available partitions.  If you don't see it there, check dmesg, and syslog (/var/log/messsages).  If you are not seeing anything there then go back to the RAID card and start over.  It's likely you will have to use a methodical iterative process to find the problem.

Comment: spot on - I diffed the contents of /dev before and after adding the drive, and sdc was the difference.  But looks like the new drive is appearing as /dev/sdb.